# is $\int_{0}^{t} dB_s = B_t$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

$(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion, first of all I know that they are equal in distribution but as I was solving the Geometric Brownian motion SDE I got a solution of the form :

$$X_t = X_0 \exp((r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma\int_{0}^{t} dB_s)$$

but the solution that is written in the lecture notes I'm reading from is of the form :

$$X_t = X_0 \exp((r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma B_t)$$

Am I wrong and should review my work or are the two forms the same thing ?

Comment: You should review your work, because $\int_0^t dB_s = B_t$ does indeed hold.

Comment: @LukasRollier you mean doesn't hold ?

Comment: Oh, I read your first line wrong. It does indeed hold, so you shouldn't review your work :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485264/easy-question-on-stochastic-integral/3485289#3485289